# kubernetes + traefik gitlab ssh

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, traefik

For couple of days I'm trying to figure out a way to access gitlab over ssh hosted on a k8s cluster

So, kubernetes 1.23.13; traefik 2.8.7
Kubernetes cluster up and running

gitlab service exposed with ports 80,443,22

Here is the ingressroutetcp  for ssh access

```
- apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
  kind: IngressRouteTCP
  metadata:
    name: gitlab-ssh
    namespace: gitlab
  spec:
    entryPoints:
    - gitlab-ssh
    routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: HostSNI(`*`)
      priority: 2
      services:
      - name: gitlab-ce
        port: 22
```

Since kubernetes + traefik are already in place/running, I had to patch the running traefik deploy to create entrypoint::

```
...
...

spec:
  containers:
  - args:
    - --global.checknewversion
    - --global.sendanonymoususage
    - --entrypoints.metrics.address=:9100/tcp
    - --entrypoints.traefik.address=:9000/tcp
    - --entrypoints.web.address=:8000/tcp
    - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:8443/tcp
    - --entrypoints.gitlab-ssh.address=:2222/tcp
```

...
...

```
   ports:
    - containerPort: 8000
      name: web
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 8443
      name: websecure
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 2222
      name: gitlab-ssh
```

traefik service has already exposed ports:80,443,2222

Basically, if I ssh mydomain-k8s.dk -p 2222 I should be able to access gitlab shell,
But, plain and simple I;m unable to connect, the sshd service on gitlab pod is running on port 22...

To mention, I have 2 ingressroutetcp: 1 for ssl passthrough and  2nd one for ssh...

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Share the error you are getting while trying to connect and also Traefik has a dedicated entry point  `--entrypoints.gitlab-ssh.address=:22`. Try by adding this in entrypoint might help you in resolving this issue.

Comment: if I add  `--entrypoints.gitlab-ssh.address=:22`
i get this error: 
 command traefik error: error while building entryPoint gitlab-ssh: error preparing server: error opening listener: listen tcp :22: bind: permission denied

If I let as I've modified 1st time: `--entrypoints.gitlab-ssh.address=:2222`
I just get ssh timeout....

Comment: As per this [gitlink](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/issues/336) add the           `add: [NET_BIND_SERVICE]` in the security context this will clear the bind: permission denied issue.